# Tracking a conversion on a different domain in SiteCatalyst

Tags: adobe-analytics

Is it just a matter of asking them to add the s_code on their conversion page and send to our metrics.ourcompany.com? Is there an issue with sessions etc when there are pages on their domain in between the conversion event that does not have the s_code?

So for example

1. User clicks "browse inventor" on mydomain.com
2. User clicks a link going to theirdomain.com, adds products to the shopping cart
3. User hits purchase and goes to theirdomain.com/thankyou

Is it enough to add the s_code on theirdomain.com/thankyou to fire an event? Is there an issue with getting this event tied to the original session?

I would like to be able to see in my original report (the one for mydomain.com) if a user converted or not on theirdomain.com (but I don't need to see any deeper information on theirdomain.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can track cross-domain activity in Adobe Analytics by doing the following:

1. Add s_code to any pages you'd like to track on theirdomain.com
2. Make sure s_account is set to the same report suite ID in both files
3. Configure the "Internal URL Filters" for your report suite to reflect both mydomain.com AND theirdomain.com (within the Admin Console)
4. Set s.linkInternalFilters in the s_code to include both mydomain.com and theirdomain.com if you do not want to see link clicks between the sites as exits.

Because you have now included theirdomain.com as part of the report suite URL filters, Adobe Analytics will see movement as part of the same visit.

As a side note, if you're loading DTM (instead of legacy s_code) the same configuration would apply but everything can be configured in the DTM UI - except the change to the Internal URL Filters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey just wanted to doube-check this question: Is there an issue with sessions etc when there are pages on their domain in between the conversion event that does not have the s_code? What I mean is, we will only have the s_code on the conversion page on their page. SO the user will click a link from our page (which has the s_code), then navigate a bunch of store pages (which do not) and then finally land on the conversion page. Does this cause any issues? Assuming correct internal URL filters, will it be considered part of the same session? Thanks!!

Comment: Nope. As long as domain B is included in the Internal URL filters and the conversion page activity doesn't occur 30 minutes after the last image request (this would constitute a new visit) then you are good to go. It doesn't matter that there are pages in between that don't have code on them.